# Is there a word for drum beats that sound like a heartbeat?

Tags: percussion

I've heard this in two songs over the years: deep, slow drum beats that sound like a heart beating. Is there a word for this unusual sound?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of I do know depending where you pop your snare at it can be a syncopated math metal beat

Answer (score 1):

It's called a "thump." It can be made by [timpani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timpani) and [bass drums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bass_drum). The term is also used to describe actual heartbeats as well as a technique for playing bass guitars.

There could be terms in other languages that relate the connotation better - certain cultures would name the instruments themselves after the sound they make; the [Djun-djun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junjung), for example.

Short of making up a word (which I'm all for :), I believe that's the term we're stuck with in the English language...

Comment: I should add that there is probably some sort of muting technique that the drummers are using to obtain the exact sound you're hearing.